# How to add a column to an existing table with Kotlin's Exposed?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-exposed

So I currently have an Exposed table

```kotlin
object Foo : Table() {
    val bar = integer("foobar").autoIncrement()
    override val primaryKey = PrimaryKey(bar)
}
```

I ran my application that contained

```kotlin
SchemaUtils.create(Foo)
```

so the table was create in the underlying schema. However, now I want to add a column to the table.

```kotlin
object Foo : Table() {
    val bar = integer("foobar").autoIncrement()
    val baz = integer("foobaz")
    override val primaryKey = PrimaryKey(bar)
}
```

But when I run my application, no SQL logging is made and when I run

```sql
SHOW COLUMNS FROM Foo;
```

in my MySQL console, I only get the first column. Exposed didn't seem to perform the table alteration. Is this typical, could I be doing something wrong somewhere else? Is there some sort of method or function I need to invoke?

Comment: You should use `SchemaUtils.createMissingTablesAndColumns()` instead.

Comment: That's perfect, thank you @Tapac! If you add that as an answer, I'd be happy to mark it as accepted